# Model prediction (real-time) in Docker became slower after some time

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, opencv, flask

Deployed trained model in the server with the docker container(with GPU support) which is a real-time prediction application. But after some time like 1 or 2 hours, the real-time prediction is becoming slow.

> **Flask code**

```
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='template')
CORS(app)
#loading model
loaded = tf.saved_model.load("./model/")
infer = loaded.signatures["serving_default"]

#default page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


#predicting mask
def generate_frames(frame, h, s, l_adjust):

    img_f = cv2.resize(frame,(256,256))    
    img_f = cv2.cvtColor(img_f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)

    #converting into float32
    img_f_f = (img_f/255.0).astype(np.float32)

    #Predicting segmentation
    final_result = infer(tf.constant(np.expand_dims(img_f_f[:,:,:3], axis=0)))['conv2d_17'][0]
    K.clear_session()
            
    final_result = (final_result*255).astype(np.uint8)
            
    ret,buffer=cv2.imencode('.jpg',final_result)

    frame=buffer.tobytes()

    return frame
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: machine overheats, throttling the GPU. move machine above arctic circle. I'm not joking. you haven't established that the code must be to blame, and it likely isn't to blame.

Comment: Are you saying it because of the hardware? is TF serving going to solve this issue?

Comment: if I re-run the container the real time works fine for few times.